# Sensitivity analysis in Python with data from Dymola (without transferring model from Dymola)

Tags: python, dymola

I want a suggestions regarding sensitivity Analysis in Python. I have a Building model from Dymola, and I simulated it for one year to check the total Energy consumption. Now ; I want to see which Parameter is affecting the most, by using Global Sensitivity Analysis in Python.

In, Python I used the Sobol SA and Ishigami function to do the sensitivity Analysis. For the Input of Ishigami function I took the total Energy consumption due to Change in each seperate Parameter. Then, I simulated it to check the first and second order Indices of Sobol method. Is it a correct way?[image: Python Code]

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace the Ishigami function with your Dymola model.

The Ishigami function is just a "test model" used to demonstrate the sensitivity analysis library.

Comment: To replace the Ishigami function with my Dymola model, should I transfer it with FMPy or just create an equation of my model like the Ishigami function? @willu47

Comment: Pass the sample generated by SALib to your Dymola model. Then analyze the outputs from your Dymola model using the relevant analyze method.